# FindRoot error in NDSolve

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I have two coupled differential equations as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}U[x,y] &=&2V[x,y],  \notag \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}V[x,y] &=&V[x,y]U[x,y]+1,
\end{eqnarray}
with conditions
\begin{equation}
U[0,y]=\sin [y]\,,\qquad V[x,0]=0.
\end{equation}
To solve the above equations with the NDSolve command in Mathematica, the following errors are
obtained

[image]

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Looks like the primary source of error is the PDE’s behavior itself. This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423985/what-is-convection-dominated-pde-problems